# Python3 Memory Error while modifying large dataset

Tags: python-3.x, memory, out-of-memory

I am trying to implement symspell in python3 (64 bit) and I have a txt file that is 20 MB which includes words with frequencies. I can successfully load this data to a dictionary named `originalDictionary` . As a next step for every word in the dictionary I should delete one char at a time and also add that modified word to another dictionary called `editDictionary`. But I got a memory error. 
I am running this on Windows10(x64) with 16gb RAM.
What can i do to tackle this problem?

```
 for word in originalDictionary:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        edit1 = word[0:i] + word[i + 1:]
        if edit1 not in editedDictionary:
            editedDictionary[edit1] = [word]
        else:
            editedDictionary[edit1].append(word)
```

Below is error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/ee/PycharmProjects/SymSpell/spellCorrector.py", line 98, in <module>
    createDictionaries()
  File "C:/Users/ee/PycharmProjects/SymSpell/spellCorrector.py", line 40, in createDictionaries
    editedDictionary[edit1] = [word]
MemoryError
```

Comment: Please show the full error message and what line it occurred on.

Comment: Some statistics may be helpful. Like the number of entries in the dictionary, how many iterations it gets through before getting the memory error, and what the overall virtual memory usage is. I found this to do the latter. `import psutil` & 
`print(psutil.virtual_memory())` although it needs to be installed with pip.

Comment: It is a pretty big scale you're working on though. The size of the original dictionary is multiplied by more than the average length of each word.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of the SymSpell algorithm you can define a prefix length. Only within this prefix the deletes are generated. A shorter prefix length significantly reduces the memory consumption, at the expense of slower lookup time. A prefix length = 5 is usually a good compromise.

There is a Python port of SymSpell available which supports setting the prefix length:
https://github.com/mammothb/symspellpy